# How to select the last inserted row in a table?

Tags: java, swing

I have a table model. Adding, and editing rows works perfectly. But How is it possible, to select the last row, like when the user clicks on it?

```
public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not clear - "Java select the last inserted row in a tabe" Where are you clicking?

Comment: maybe duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179016/how-to-auto-select-the-last-inserted-row-in-jtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can order by id desc and limit 1, 
or order by created_at desc limit 1
if you have this rows